# Make Facebook pixel fire on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, events, onclick

I'm currently trying to follow [this FB resource](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/conversion-pixel-code-migration#in-page-events) about tracking on page events with conversion pixels.

If I'm understanding correctly, the gist of it is to paste my base pixel code in the header, then add the tweaked "example code" underneath it.

Here is our base pixel code:

```
<!-- Facebook Conversion Code for Cool Company LLC -->
<script>(function() {
   var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
   if (!_fbq.loaded) {
      var fbds = document.createElement('script');
      fbds.async = true;
      fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
     _fbq.loaded = true;
   }
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(['track', '6029151989664', {'value':'0.00','currency':'USD'}]);
</script>
    <noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=6029151989664&amp;cd[value]=0.00&amp;cd[currency]=USD&amp;noscript=1" /></noscript>
```

And here is the "example code" they say to use for tracking in-page events:

```
  function trackConversionEvent(val, cny) {
    var cd = {};
    cd.value = val;
    cd.currency = cny;
   _fbq.push(['track', '<pixel_id>', cd]);
  }
 <button onClick="trackConversionEvent('10.00','USD');" />
```

And finally the question: we want the in-page event to be hitting the submit button on the rightside subscription widget at http://wearablestylenews.com/

To do this, do I just change the last line of example code to this?

```
 <input id="ykfmc-submit_0-2f6a0367b1" onClick="trackConversionEvent('0.00','USD');" />
```

And do I just put it after the base code in the header?

Thanks guys, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You have to put the onClick callback on the button that submit the action (i.e. usually the Buy button). Remember to set the proper amount instead of just leaving it at '0.00'.